# Probability of moving on a cartesian plane

Tags: python, math, probability, combinatorics

I am working on the below coding problem which looks more like a probability question rather than a coding problem

platform consisting of 5 vertices. The coordinates of the vertices are: (-1,0), (0.-1). (0,0), (0.1). (1.0).
You start at vertex (xs,ys)
and keep moving randomly either left (i.e., x coordinate decreases by 1), right (i.e., x coordinate increases by 1), up, or
down. The direction of subsequent moves is independent.
What is the probability that you reach vertex (xe, ye)
before falling off the platform?
Constraints:
(xs, ys) in [(-1.0), (0.-1), (0.0), (0.1), (1,0)]
(xe, ye) in [(-1,0), (0.-1), (0,0), (0,1), (1.0)]
xs != xend or ys != yend

below is what I implemented which works for the case I shared but fails for all other cases

```
def calculate_probability(xs, ys, xe, ye):
    edges = [[-1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
    if [xs, ys] in edges:
        if xe == 0 and ye == 0:
            return 0.25
        elif xs == xe and ys == ye:
            return 1.0
        elif [xe, ye] in edges:
            return 0.075
    
    if xs == 0 and ys == 0:
        if [xe, ye] in edges:
            return 0.3
        elif xe == 0 and ye == 0:
            return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: What is your actual question here?  What went wrong when you tried to implement this?

Comment: @jasonharper added my implementation

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter: Agreed that this is more of a mathematics problem than a coding problem. Unless you're thinking of writing a simulation (which I'd definitely recommend even if you're looking for an exact solution, as a way of validating your maths results).

Comment: @MarkDickinson do you mind sharing how the simulation would look like? If its an infinite GP then the simulation  might not work because it will go in an. infinite loop?

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter: in theory the loop could be infinite; in practice the chance of hitting an infinite loop is ridiculously small (theoretically probability zero if we ignore the fact that we're using a PRNG), so it's not a problem for a simulation. If you're still worried about infinite loops, you could always cut things short after 1000 steps (or so) - at that point it won't have any statistically measurable impact on the outcome. I didn't bother, and was still able to execute `10**9` iterations without hitting an infinite loop.

Comment: As to code: I have a `step` function that takes a random step from a given position and returns the new position, a `walk` function that takes a starting position and steps until it hits the goal position or falls off (and returns a `bool` indicating which of those two things happened), and a `driver` function that drives the simulation. No more than 20 lines of code in all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we handle the edge cases where you start at your destination, or you start at an edge and the destination is the center, we're left with a simple scenario: find you way to the center, and then to the destination. Getting to the origin is a flat `0.25` probability, and then its just a matter of getting to the right edge. If you randomly walk in the wrong direction, you can always backtrack with `0.25` probability of success. This can repeat any number of times before walking in the correct direction (to the destination).

This means from the origin, we have a 1/4 chance of picking the right direction, and a 3/4 chance of picking the wrong direction. If we pick the right direction, we're done, if we pick the wrong direction, we have to pick the opposite direction to get back to the origin and avoid falling off, which  is a 1/4 chance. Combining these into one, we have a 1/4 of being right the first time, and 3/16 chance at a second chance. Continuing this repeatedly, we end up with a formula like:

```
1/4 + 1/4 * (3/16) + 1/4 * (3/16)^2 + 1/4 * (3/16)^3 + ...
= 1/4 * (1 + (3/16) + (3/16)^2 + (3/16)^3 + ...)
= 1/4 * (16/13)
= 4/13
```

So from the origin, we have a `4/13` chance of walking to the correct edge tile without falling off.

In code:

```py
def solve(xs, ys, xe, ye):
    # already at destination
    if xs == xe and ys == ye:
        return 1

    # if destination is the origin, the probability is a flat 0.25
    if xe == 0 and ye == 0:
        return 0.25

    # first move must take you to the origin if not already there
    prob = 0.25 if xs != 0 or ys != 0 else 1

    # multiply by probability of walking from origin to destination
    return prob * 4 / 13
```

**Update**: I have an alternative and possibly simpler way of approaching the math in the section above.

Take `P` to represent the probability of successfully walking from the origin to the destination without falling off. Ignore the edge case where the origin is the destination- that's already handled above. We know have two cases to handle:

- The first move takes is to the destination. This has a 1/4 chance of happening.
- The first move takes us in one of the other 3 directions (3/4 chance). We then have to return to the origin, with a 1/4 chance of not falling off. We then repeat the process recursively, with a `P` chance of success (by definition of `P`). This gives `3/16 * P` chance for this scenario.

This means we have algebraically:

```
P = 1/4 + 3/16 * P
13/16 * P = 1/4
P = 4/13
```

We arrive at the same probability of `4/13` as before.

Comment: still same result. Isnt working for any case

Comment: I think you want `3/16` in place of `3/8`, leading to a probability of `4/13` for a center-to-given-non-center-tile transition.

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes, you're right - updated the answer accordingly

Comment: hi @DillonDavis, Could you explain why we have a 3/16 chance at the second chance?

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc starting at the origin, you have 3 incorrect directions to pick from (if you pick the correct direction, you "win" on the first chance), from 4 total directions, so 3/4 chance. Once the step is taken, you need to step back towards the origin, with only one valid move (regardless of which of the 3 directions you previously stepped in), so 1/4 chance of stepping back to the origin safely. Combining these, we get 3/16 chance to step off the origin (without immediately "winning") and then returning safely.

Comment: @DillonDavis, thanks for your clearly explain, but I have a few questions:

1. Suppose I choose a wrong move and I want to get back to the origin (in my mind: origin is a center (0,0)), I just choose the opposite move with my previous move so why do I have a `1/4` chance of stepping back to the origin safely? If I choose to go up before, I just literally choose to go down and I think my probability is 100% to get back to the origin safely.

Comment: 2. Why is the probability of incorrect directions not decreasing with multiple-time re-choose? If my previous move is wrong, I will have other 2 incorrect directions

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc because in the original problem, it says that you move randomly

Comment: hi @DillonDavis, thank you for your answer, I didn't read the problem clearly. I understand now, thank you again.